# How I can create a User in AD with Powershell in a ASP.NET Webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, active-directory, powershell-remoting

I have a question to C# and Powershell in a ASP.NET Application.

I want to create a User in our Active Directory and I want/must use a powershell for this. I had built a Webapllication that could add a mailcontact in the Exchange Server one year ago. For this I used the System.Management.Automation Namespace with the Powershell Classes. But I don't know how I can do it for the Active Directory.

the ps command that I must use:

```
New-ADUser %prefix-%name 
-SamAccountName "%name" 
-UserPrincipalName "%name@test-company.com" 
-GivenName "%text1" 
-SurName "%text2" 
-displayname "%name" 
-enabled $true 
-Path '%OU' 
-AllowReversiblePasswordEncryption $true 
-PasswordNeverExpires $true 
-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-Securestring "%name" -asplaintext -Force)
```

and here my cs code:

```
public void CreateRemoteConnectionToActiveDirectory(string Username, string password//,...comming)
        {
            SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();

            str_password = password;
            str_username = Username;

            foreach (char x in str_password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(x);
            }

            PSCredential cred = new PSCredential(str_username, securePassword); 

          //  connection?
        }
```

My Old Code for the exchange Server:

```
public string CreateRemoteConnectionToExchange(string UserName, string Password, string Mailbox)
        {
                SecureString SecurePassword = new SecureString();

                string str_password = Password;
                string str_username = UserName;

                foreach (char x in str_password)
                {
                    SecurePassword.AppendChar(x);
                }

                PSCredential cred = new PSCredential(str_username, SecurePassword);

                WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(ExchangeServer), Schema, cred);

                connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Default;

                Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);

                PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
                PSCommand command = new PSCommand();

                command.AddCommand("New-MailContact");
                command.AddParameter("ExternalEmailAddress", "SMTP:" + Mailbox + MailExtension);
                command.AddParameter("Name", Mailbox);
                command.AddParameter("Alias", Mailbox);
                command.AddParameter("FirstName", Mailbox);
                command.AddParameter("Initials", "");
                command.AddParameter("LastName", "");
                command.AddParameter("OrganizationalUnit", OrganizationalUnit);
                command.AddParameter("DomainController", configDC);

                powershell.Commands = command;

                try
                {
                    runspace.Open();

                    powershell.Runspace = runspace;

                    powershell.Invoke();


                    return "Der Kontakt wurde Erfolgreich erstellt";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                 ///...
                }
                finally
                {
                    runspace.Dispose();
                    runspace = null;
                    powershell.Dispose();
                    powershell = null;
                }


        }
```

How I can do this. A Example,tutorial or a tipp would me help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your connection just needs to connect to either your AD server or another server that can actually execute the command.

Comment: WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(ActiveDirectory), Schema, cred); For Example: ActiveDirectory = LDAP://OU=NPS,OU=services,DC=test-company,DC=com ? or how I built this connectionstring?

Comment: Tarasov, did you ever find out what the new URI should be for active directory?